# Update another item in same Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, document-set, updatelistitems

I have a **SharePoint 2013** Library with 2 content types assigned:

1. Document Set
2. Document

Both have a (non-shared) choice field called "Stage" with the following Choices:

1. Stage 1
2. Stage 2
3. Stage 3

The Document Set has "Stage 1" set by default.

What I want to do in my **SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow** is the following :

- If **any** item inside the Document Set gets set to "Stage 2", I want the Document Set to also Show Stage 2.
- If **any** item inside the Document Set gets set to "Stage 3", I want the Document Set to also Show Stage 3.

I just can't figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The logic will be like : 
When item updated in your list (Docset or document)

Check if stage have changed (you can create a second stage_last value that store the last stage value)

If stage == stage_last 
    Do nothing 
Else 
    Find docset 
    Update docset stage 
    Update stage_last value

Ps: stage last default value will be stage 1 and have to be updated at the end of the workflow changed

Hope that's clear for you

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I'm a bit confused with this. Not sure how to target another item in the same list.

Comment: You can use rest api to query the list item and use it in the workflow.

Comment: Ah, I'm stuck with the 2010 Workflows, unfortunately.